How to fix this error: Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserBusService' type
I am learning from other people's projects and following along with the code. After I finished writing the relevant code for a certain chapter, the following error occurred.
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserBusService' type.
Beans:
userBusService   (UserBusService.java) 
userBusServiceImpl   (UserBusServiceImpl.java)

The specific corresponding gitHub submission is The above error occurred after my latest (fourth) code submission.
The project code I ran for study was normal. I checked for a long time but couldn't find the problem. Some information said to replace @Autowired with @Resource, or use @Qualifier, but this was not used in the reference code.
I would like to ask what went wrong. Looking forward to your reply

Does this answers your question?

I suspect your @MapperScan annotation on CommonApp. According to the MyBatis documentation, it creates a bean for every interface it finds in your package (the emphasis in the following is mine:)

<mybatis:scan/> supports filtering the mappers created by either specifying a marker interface or an annotation. The annotation property specifies an annotation to search for. The marker-interface attribute specifies a parent interface to search for. If both properties are specified, mappers are added for interfaces that match either criteria. By default, these two properties are null, so all interfaces in the given base package(s) will be loaded as mappers.

I suggest you try replacing @MapperScan("org.example") with @MapperScan("org.example.common.domain.service.user.mapper") as that's where your mapper lives.

Thank you very much. This does solve the above problem, but when I call the login interface, the backend crashes with error message org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): org.example.common.domain.service.user.mapper.UserMapper.findUserByName. I don't know if this is related to the configuration

I checked the mapper-related code and found no discrepancies.

It does look like it should work. One suggestion I have is to abandon the XML mapper file and annotate your interface method instead:  @Select("select * from sys_user_t where username = #{username}")UserEntity findUserByName(String username);. Another is to add a parameterType="String" attribute into your mapper XML element but I'm not sure this will help because it should be inferred.

If a type has two objects placed in an IOC container, an error message will be reported: There is more than one bean of. You can use the @ Qualifier annotation to add the @ Qualifier value to the UserBusService class, which is the unique identifier (id) of the bean injected into the IOC container by the current class
